# AWS Chime: How to sign an HTTP Request for Create Meeting API in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-chime-sdk

I didn't find any useful way to generate the Signature V4 in java for signing an AWS Chime HttpRequest. I want to use 3 apis of Aws Chime (Create meeting, create attendee and delete meeting) inside my java code.

Can anyone help me please !

### API Details:

> Url: https://service.chime.aws.amazon.com/meetings
>
> Body: {    "ClientRequestToken": "AXEXAMPLE",     "MediaRegion":
>   "us-east-2" }
>
> Headers:  "content-type", "application/json" "host",
>   "service.chime.aws.amazon.com" "x-amz-date", "20200526T094404Z"
>   "authorization", ?(Generated Signature)
>
> API Key: JHDCHGEXAEXAMPLE Secret Key : 4sjfkkjffs/sfkkh/sfkj/example

```
private Response createMeeting() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Response response = null;

    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n\t\"ClientRequestToken\": \"AXEXAMPLE\",\n   \"MediaRegion\": \"us-east-2\"\n}");
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url("https://service.chime.aws.amazon.com/meetings")
      .post(body)
      .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
      .addHeader("host", "service.chime.aws.amazon.com")
      .addHeader("content-length", "68")
      .addHeader("x-amz-date", getIsoDate())
      .addHeader("authorization", "?????????") //To be replaced by generated signature 
      .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
      .build();
    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println("ResponseMessage===========> " + response.message());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error===========> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}
```

**The error I am getting is:** *The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.*

Comment: Im trying to do same like you, Can you please help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64762558/integrate-aws-chime-in-java-application)