# Integrate AWS Chime in Java application

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I'm trying to build a Java Spring boot application that is used to Create/Join and chat by using AWS Chime. I've gone through the demo code provided by chime. But is running by node.js .
Can anyone help me how to integrate and consume APIS of chime by using mvc.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @Noshaf not yet, still working on it.

Comment: you using aws_chime_sdk_js ? do let me know if that works for you i am working on same .. it will be great help

Comment: @Noshaf I tried below way for back end service. I'm trying to build customised UI with react that can able to do Audi and video calls and can share files.

Answer (score 5):

I am going through the same issue and I have found some very basic first steps.

1. Go through key concepts https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/dg/meetings-sdk.html
2. Get "aws-java-sdk-chime" java module from maven repository
3. Create AmazonChime instance as an entry point to the server side Chime API. The setup is something more generic so you would work similar way with the AWS server SDKs

   ```
   AmazonChime chime = AmazonChimeClient.builder()......build();
   ```
4. The java SDK looks generated (at leas partially) from something more generic. But it looks really aligned with this documentation that is not Java specific:
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/APIReference/API_Meeting.html
   You can find API description here with data types and various actions you can perform. The related Java documentation is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/chime/AmazonChime.html but the generic above seems to me more readable.
5. Use AmazonChime instance to create various objects you need (Meeting, Attendee, ..) and serve data from created objects (like media urls, etc..) to client applications.

Hope that it helped a little bit,
Lukas

Comment: Thanks for info. Actually I've gone through this. I'm trying to build an UI that can able to make audio / video calls & can able to transfer files in that. I'm using React Js for front end and Java services for backend.  It could be more helpful to me, if you tell me how to comsume AWS Chime in react js. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry I can't helps with this. My focus is backend

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this in ASP.NET. Basically what I did was got the app running in Node.JS. Then I figured out how to extract the .HTML, .CSS and javascript using Chrome devtools and pasted them into files that I created within my project and it worked.

Now that I have it in a ASP.NET MVC app I am able to take it from there. The main issue now is that the javascript file is huge and hard to work with but I am slowly getting somewhere with it.